# The PHY on eth0 keeps restarting. How can I keep it on?

Tags: ethernet, nic

This is probably a superuser.com question, but it isn't online yet.

The PHY on my NIC is blinking on and off ridiculously, and it should always be on.  I googled it and found no answers, just questions.

http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=eth0+keeps+restarting&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=

This is on Linux (Ubuntu 8.10) with a Broadcom 100Base-T NIC:

lspci output:
01:09.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401 100Base-T (rev 01)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in my googling for a solution I came across `ethtool`.  I decided to try disabling the pause auto-negotiation after perusing its man page...

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off
```

So far so good; the PHY is not being turned off.  I added this command to `/etc/rc.local` for now, but perhaps there is a better place.

Comment: In that case there's most likely a faulty cable and/or switch (possibly just one port). Try swapping them just in case.

Comment: Turns out the ethtool idea doesn't work.

I tried a new cable, and a different port on my switch, but that doesn't solve it either.  I guess I'll put a different NIC in this server.

Comment: The new NIC with the original cable and switch port work flawlessly.  No more messages in /var/log/messages:

Jun 23 21:08:17 banjo kernel: [  404.496415] b44: eth0: powering down PHY
Jun 23 21:08:17 banjo kernel: [  405.000090] b44: eth0: Link is down.
Jun 23 21:08:20 banjo kernel: [  408.000092] b44: eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex.

Comment: Here is the Ubuntu bug report for the Broadcom driver:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/279102

Answer (score 0):

You probably checked this already, but since you didn't mention anything about this... is your networking cable alright? This is usually a symptom of a bad physical connection (cable or connector).